# Dynamic periodic update python bokeh

Tags: python, dynamic, charts, stream, bokeh

I have the following bokeh code how do you add a horizontal line or glyph to the chart dynamically do I need a callback?

In the documentation http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html it says "Custom callbacks like these can be set using a CustomJS object and passing it as the callback argument to a Widget object."

So do I set the call back before or after the update...

```
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    time=[], average=[], low=[], high=[], open=[], close=[],
    ma=[], macd=[], macd9=[], macdh=[], color=[]
))

#main chart
p = figure(plot_height=500, tools="xpan,xwheel_zoom,xbox_zoom,reset,crosshair,hover", x_axis_type=None, y_axis_location="right")
p.x_range.follow = "end"
p.x_range.follow_interval = 100
p.x_range.range_padding = 0
p.axis.minor_tick_in = -2
p.axis.minor_tick_out = 5

p.segment(x0='time', y0='low', x1='time', y1='high', line_width=2, color='black', source=source)
p.segment(x0='time', y0='open', x1='time', y1='close', line_width=8, color='color', source=source)

...
@count()
def update(t):
    open, high, low, close, average = _get_prices(t)
    color = "green" if open < close else "red"

    new_data = dict(
        time=[t],
        open=[open],
        high=[high],
        low=[low],
        close=[close],
        color=[color],
    )
    print(open)
    source.stream(new_data, 300)

output_notebook()
curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 50)
curdoc().title = "OHLC"
```

Comment: What widget are you trying to attach the callback to?